# Similarity of the solutions

Tags: matrices, optimization, normed-spaces, matrix-decomposition, constraints

I am trying to solve the following rank-k decomposition $$\Sigma \approx W\Lambda W^T$$
where $\Sigma \in R^{n \times n}$  is a positive definite symmetric matrix having diagonal elements 1, $\Lambda \in R^{k \times k}$ is a diagonal matrix having positive element. Let the columns of $W$ matrix be $w^l$ then $\| w^l\|_1 \leq \alpha$ and $\| w^l\|_\infty \leq 1$. I am trying to show that for a given $\alpha$, all the solutions of the below equation are similar $$\text{arg min}_W \|\Sigma - W\Lambda W^T \|_F$$
Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be two solutions then the average correlation between columns of $W_1$ and $W_2$ is very high i.e. the solutions are similar. The idea here is that if I constrain $W$ then the solution of the above minimization problem becomes constrain such that they lie in a similar landscape. But, I don't know how to prove this.

Edit 1: Let $\Sigma \approx W_1\Lambda_1 W_1^T \approx W_2\Lambda_2 W_2^T$ where the elements in $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$ are sorted from high to low. Now the similarity is defined as $\frac{1}{k}\sum_{l=1}^{k}corr(w_1^l,w_2^l)$ where $corr$ is the correlation.

Comment: Could you mathematically describe how you measure similarity? This would help a lot.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: I think correlation is not the correct measure here as you would use correlation in the context of statistics and random variables.

Comment: Do you have suggestions for a good measure? I am open right now, still trying to figure the best measures and how to solve the problem.

Comment: What about $|| W_1 - W_2||_F$ as a measure?

Comment: $\|W_1-W_2 \|_F$ cannot be used as a measure because $w_1^l$ and $w_2^l$ can be on different scales, this is due to $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$. That is why I was using correlation as a measure.

Comment: The Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem may be relevant here (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Mirsky_theorem_(for_Frobenius_norm) )

Comment: I tried that previously but couldn't come with anything.